# Не работает метод hide() JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не работает hide() во второй строке, т.е. элемент при загрузке все-таки отображается...
Собственно код:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.spoiler-body').hide();
  $('.spoiler-head').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
    var $self = $(this).children().children();
    if ($self.html() == "gear_fill") {
      $self.html("gear")
    } else {
      $self.html("gear_fill")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-block">
  <ul id="lifecycle spoiler-body">
    <li>
      <a href="#waterfall" class="item-link item-content">
        <div class="item-media"><i class="f7-icons colorDark">layers_fill</i>
        </div>
        <div class="item-inner">
          <div class="item-title">Модель</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `id="lifecycle spoiler-body"` это Вы считаете нормальным?

Comment: Глаз замылен, с вами не бывало после 1500 строк кода? Спасибо...

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, а что не так с id?

Comment: @Grundy The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value **must not contain** any space characters.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, но если очень хочется, [то можно](https://jsfiddle.net/vp8fo4ht/)

Comment: @Grundy можно и `td` запихнуть в `div`, но кому от этого будет хорошо?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, с td могут быть и проблемы, в зависимости от браузера. А вот с id - Нет

Comment: @Grundy Если бы браузеры изначально не ложили на стандарты - легче было бы всем

Comment: @PrinceOFF не стоит так резко реагировать на минусы. Это довольно обычная ситуация, случается со всеми, даже с теми у кого больше ста тысяч репутации на сайте )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы обращаетесь к классу, а атрибут в разметке указан как айди:

```
<ul id="lifecycle spoiler-body">
```

Чтобы код заработал, надо исправить, например, разметку вот так:

```
<ul id="lifecycle" class="spoiler-body">
```

Comment: Спасибо, товарищи - глаз замылен, думаю вы понимаете что это такое... Можно и без минусов было обойтись.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в `css`

```
.spoiler-body {
    display:none;
}
```

`.hide()` при загрузке не срабатывает, т.к. пока интерпретатор `js` не дойдет до `hide()` - элемент не скроется

Comment: а почему _при загрузке не срабатывает_? :-)

Comment: Не работает данный метод, все по прежнему... У меня по идее самовызывающаяся функция, должна сразу прятать блок...

Comment: @PrinceOFF хотите сказать, что после этого элемент всё еще видно на странице?

Comment: да, видно - я внес в css ваш блок

Comment: @PrinceOFF можете добавить в вопрос html, с которым работает данный скрипт?

Comment: Добавил !important в css-правило... Все равно не отображается... HTML - даже не знаю стоит ли добавлять - пару дивов вложенных друг в друга...

Answer (score 0):

Нет у Вас при загрузке элемента `.spoiler-body` он появляется после загрузки всего документа. Перенесите Ваш код в обработчик `DOMReady`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.spoiler-body').hide();
  $('.spoiler-head').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
    var $self = $(this).children().children();
    if ($self.html() == "gear_fill") {
      $self.html("gear")
    } else {
      $self.html("gear_fill")
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: у меня данный код уже находится в обработчике для моей аппы onAppReady()

Comment: боюсь нет такой переменной: `JQuery`

Comment: @Grundy а Вы не бойтесь. Просто загляните в документацию http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, советую присмотреться к тому что по приведенной ссылке в документации написано, и то, что используется в коде, и в моем комментарии. Прям вот побуквенно сравнить ;-)

Comment: @Grundy убедили :)